# C++ function declaration

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, void

I have seen in C++ program, during function declaration if there is no parameter for the function void is declared as parameter like this:

```
int F1(void)
```

How is it different than:

```
int F1()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Using `void` is just a more explicit way to declare the same thing. Personally, I never use that syntax and rarely see anyone else use it either.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing in C++, and is a holdover from C.

Here's an excerpt from the C++ 2003 standard (C.1.6):

> **Change:** In C++, a function declared with an empty parameter list takes no arguments.
>   In C, an empty parameter list means that the number and type of the function arguments are unknown"
>   Example:
>
> ```
>  int f(); // means int f(void) in C++
>           // intf(unknown) in C
> ```
>
> **Rationale:** This is to avoid erroneous function calls (i.e. function calls with the wrong number or type of arguments).
>
> **Effect on original feature:** Change to semantics of well-defined feature. This feature was marked as “obsolescent” in C.

Comment: "a holdover from C" – what do you mean? In C, those are two different things.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are exactly the same, leaving the argument field empty as () is the one I prefer, some prefer writing (void) just so that someone editing the code may be ensured that no arguments are required. Makes no difference though, just a readability thing.